# C++ Passing Array to Function and Then Passing It to Another Function

Tags: c++

I try to use array from main function that is pass into a function and into another function. Below is the simplified version of what I'm trying to do.

I can't put `func2()` in the main function because the code I was doing require me to do something in `void func()` and then apply to `void func2()`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void func(char arr[2])
{
    func2(arr);
}

void func2(char arr[2])
{
    cout << arr[0] << arr[1];
}

int main()
{
    char arr[2] = {1,2};
    func(arr);
}
```

**Edit:**
Seems like the problem is the order of the function instead of something wrong with the array which I originally thought it was.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void func2(char arr[2])
{
    cout << arr[0] << arr[1];
}

void func(char arr[2])
{
    func2(arr);
}

int main()
{
     char arr[2] = {1,2};
     func(arr);
}
```

Comment: Your example will fail because func2 is declared after func

Comment: I can't seems to pass the array to func2()

Comment: See @Dillanm 's comment. You must declare `func2` before you use it.

Comment: @Nasx Why can't you do it? Is there an error? What is the error message? It may hint at the issue.

Comment: @Dillanm Oh it works, seems like I just got the order wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try, swap your functions around:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void func2(char arr[2])
{
    cout << arr[0] << arr[1];
}

void func(char arr[2])
{
    func2(arr);
}



int main()
{
    char arr[2] = {1,2};
    func(arr);
}
```

The problem is that you're referencing `func2` which `func` doesn't know anything about.

Also, try using pointers instead of copying whole arrays into functions. It's much more efficient.

Comment: There is no copying of arrays here.  `func` and `func2` both actually take a `char*` parameter.